# Failed to start LSB: Enable AMQP service provided by RabbitMQ broker

Tags: rabbitmq

I am trying to start the rabbitmq server in centos 7

```
[root@localhost ~]# /sbin/service rabbitmq-server start
Starting rabbitmq-server (via systemctl):  Job for rabbitmq-server.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status rabbitmq-server.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

then showing this status

```
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl status rabbitmq-server.service
● rabbitmq-server.service - LSB: Enable AMQP service provided by RabbitMQ broker
Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/rabbitmq-server; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since 2017-05-05 18:32:08 CST; 10s ago
Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
Process: 5196 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/rabbitmq-server start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
5月 05 18:32:06 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Enable AMQP service provided by RabbitMQ broker...
5月 05 18:32:06 localhost.localdomain su[5206]: (to rabbitmq) root on none
5月 05 18:32:06 localhost.localdomain su[5267]: (to rabbitmq) root on none
5月 05 18:32:06 localhost.localdomain su[5269]: (to rabbitmq) root on none
5月 05 18:32:08 localhost.localdomain rabbitmq-server[5196]: Starting rabbitmq-server: FAILED - check /var/log/rabbitmq/startup_{log, _err}
5月 05 18:32:08 localhost.localdomain rabbitmq-server[5196]: rabbitmq-server.
5月 05 18:32:08 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
5月 05 18:32:08 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Enable AMQP service provided by RabbitMQ broker.
5月 05 18:32:08 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit rabbitmq-server.service entered failed state.
5月 05 18:32:08 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service failed.
[root@localhost ~]# firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=5672/tcp
FirewallD is not running
[root@localhost ~]# firewall-cmd --reload
FirewallD is not running
[root@localhost ~]# setsebool -P nis_enabled 1
setsebool:  SELinux is disabled.
[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/hostname 
localhost.localdomain
[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4 saltcode
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

Check this log and err file

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /var/log/rabbitmq/startup_err 
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,sasl,{bad_return,{{sasl,start,[normal,[]]},{'EXIT',{undef,[{sasl,start,[normal,[]],[]},{application_master,start_it_old,4,[{f
Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done
[root@localhost ~]# cat /var/log/rabbitmq/startup_log 
=INFO REPORT==== 5-May-2017::18:32:06 ===
    application: sasl
    exited: {bad_return,
        {{sasl,start,[normal,[]]},
         {'EXIT',
             {undef,
             [{sasl,start,[normal,[]],[]},
              {application_master,start_it_old,4,
                  [{file,"application_master.erl"},
                   {line,273}]}]}}}}
    type: permanent
{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,sasl,{bad_return,{{sasl,start,[normal,[]]},{'EXIT',{undef,[{sasl,start,[normal,[]],[]},{application_master,start_it_old,4,[{file,\"application_master.erl\"},{line,273}]}]}}}}}"}
```

There i can speculate that is network or port config question, and someone can tell me how to resolve it?

If i run it from client directly, its seems running, but it will be stop when quit from xshell.

```
[root@localhost ~]# rabbitmq-server

          RabbitMQ 3.1.5. Copyright (C) 2007-2013 GoPivotal, Inc.
  ##  ##      Licensed under the MPL.  See http://www.rabbitmq.com/
  ##  ##
  ##########  Logs: /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost.log
  ######  ##        /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost-sasl.log
  ##########
          Starting broker... completed with 6 plugins.
```

Comment: Please post your rabbitmq.config file. I see you using RabbitMQ 3.1.5, can you try the newer versions?